# Is the emergency fluorescent floor lighting strip along the aisle an item on the MEL?

Tags: airbus, evacuation

Was travelling on a Airbus A320 (night flight) and during the safety briefing noticed that the  fluorescent floor lighting strip referred to in the evacuation instructions was totally absent.  Both sides of the aisle.

I could see the marks on the floor carpet where it must have been earlier tacked on. Was removed and went unreplaced for whatever reason.

Is it OK for an aircraft to fly without this item? Seemed pretty essential to me for a safe evacuation in the dark.

Edit: I did try & take a photo but unfortunately didn't come out so well.

[image]

Comment: Did you get happen to get a picture?

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot: Yes! I did actually. I'll try & post. Not sure how nice it came out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this document](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/mmel/a-320%20r21.pdf) the answer would appear to be no if all lights were missing.

[image]

The 1/1 columns indicates the number installed and required for dispatch.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to email the regulator, just to see what they say. I will report back.

Answer (score 8):

Those lights don't have to be mounted to the floor. They can also be seat mounted.

http://www.bruceind.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=90:escape-path-lighting-systems&Itemid=189

http://www.astronics.com/_images/aircraft-safety/EPM%20033010.pdf

[image: Seat mounted escape path lights]

This is the AC that provides guidance on the requirements of the system. http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC25.812-1A.pdf

The regulation is [14CFR 25.812](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=67a8813bf9d9da0aa64e74e2e5ced957&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:1.0.1.3.11.4.178.62&idno=14)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. Maybe there were other lights that I did not see? Possible. Better safe then sorry though. I'll better report to the regulator & if there was a different system then no harm done. What do people think?